# Maximum occurrences

Tags: c++, count, max, find-occurrences

I want to find the element in array which has maximum occurrences and know the number of occurrences. Please suggest me fastest C++ code to do so.(You are free to use STL if that can be of any help.)

Comment: May I suggest `vector<string> google(string)`? Your "question" sounds more like a demand, even though you might not have intended it that way.

Comment: sorry for that sir...

Comment: It sounds like homework as well.

Comment: Have you wondered what will you do when there are two or more elements with same number of occurences? E.g. {5,3,5,8,8,3}

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7291/finding-the-element-that-occurs-the-most-in-a-very-large-file

Comment: @Lyth - never even thought about that..thats why i am just a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `O(n log n)` solution to this problem in C++.

First use an `O(n log n)` sort (**Heap Sort**, **Merge Sort**, **Quick Sort**, etc.) to sort the number of elements in the list. If you don't care about the complexity of the algorithm sort the list using `Bubble Sort`. In that case the complexity of the algorithm will become **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

Then use the following code which takes `O(n)` time to find the element with highest occurrence from the sorted list.

```
maxfreq=0;
freq=1;
for(i=0;i<(MAX-1);i++)
{
  if(list[i]==list[i+1])
  {
    freq++;
    if(freq > maxfreq)
    {
      maxfreq=freq;
      maxind=i;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    freq=1;
  }
}
cout<<"Element "<<list[maxind]<<" occurs "<<maxfreq<<" times in the list";
```

The total time taken is `O(log n + n)`. Thus the complexity of the algorithm is `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way of doing it in C++11:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int most_frequent_element(std::vector<int> const& v)
{   // Precondition: v is not empty
    std::map<int, int> frequencyMap;
    int maxFrequency = 0;
    int mostFrequentElement = 0;
    for (int x : v)
    {
        int f = ++frequencyMap[x];
        if (f > maxFrequency)
        {
            maxFrequency = f;
            mostFrequentElement = x;
        }
    }

    return mostFrequentElement;
}
```

You could use the above function this way:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5 };
    std::cout << most_frequent_element(v);
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/Rsqu4F).

With a minor modification, the above function can be generalized to work with any container (not just `std::vector`):

```
template<typename T>
typename T::value_type most_frequent_element(T const& v)
{    // Precondition: v is not empty
    std::map<typename T::value_type, int> frequencyMap;
    int maxFrequency = 0;
    typename T::value_type mostFrequentElement{};
    for (auto&& x : v)
    {
        int f = ++frequencyMap[x];
        if (f > maxFrequency)
        {
            maxFrequency = f;
            mostFrequentElement = x;
        }
    }

    return mostFrequentElement;
}
```

Thanks to template type deduction, you would call the above function template exactly like you called the original one.

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/2kAg1a).

Also, for even better performance, you may consider using C++11's [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) rather than `std::map`. `std::unordered_map` gives you amortized O(1) complexity for insertion and lookup. I'll leave its usage in the above examples up to you as an exercise.